# Battery maintenance for Lenovo laptop

Tags: battery, maintenance

I have a Lenovo laptop with W10/64, and I want to do a battery maintenance. Which software is best to do a battery maintenance?
Lenovo offered a battery maintenance procedure in the Lenovo settings. The features were charging, discharging the battery to increase capacity, and setting limits for charging when plugged in: e.g. 30% to 70% charge, which means that the battery hardly ages. But they dropped this feature. Therefore, I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: What do you mean by battery maintenance? If you want to replace the battery you don't need any software.

Comment: The maintenance charges and discharges the battery to increase the lifetime of the battery.

Comment: So does using the laptop with the power cable unplugged and later charging it with the cable plugged. Honestly, you're probably riding a myth here: modern batteries no longer have a "memory effect", so "calibration" shouldn't be needed. If you still insist, please [edit] your post and mention at least the OS it should run on, and how much you're willing to spend if it comes to paid software.

Comment: @Izzy - Li-ion batteries don't have memory effect, but many people believe they stay healthier longer if they are kept in a "comfort zone" that is isn't too deeply discharged or too fully charged. I don't know if modern Li-ion-powered devices have built-in power management that already leaves a buffer zone on either end (e.g. reporting "out of charge" when the battery chemically still has some safe, usable amount of charge left). If not, then there's still room for software to handle this kind of thing so you don't have to keep manually plugging and unplugging.

Comment: You mean if the power cable is plugged in permanently, @JohnY? Then my 10 year old laptop should have died long ago :) // But OK, whatever it is, OP needs to [edit] the question and clarify.